# C# webbrowser control - I want to use / link a specific font

Tags: c#, fonts, controls, browser

I'm writing a simple textviewer for the famous .nfo files.
For easy layout stuff I'm using the webbrowser control to display the nfo file.
I have font - nonstandard ofcourse - that I'd like to use.

What's the best way to include / link the font in my application ?
Do I have to include it in my application-folder and register it, or is there a way to use a font in my control that's not standard installed ?

Comment: Why are you using a web browser instead of a fixed-width text box?  Hyperlinks?

Comment: ASCII art?  Isn't it the point to use the lousiest font available on Windows and the worst output way (console) and still make it look good?

Answer (score 0):

The fonts are not part of the web control. The fonts come from the HTML of the web page that you're viewing with the web control.

So, the first step is to make a sample HTML page that displays correctly in a browser (with the fonts you want), then you can load that page into the webcontrol later.

To load fonts in the html page, see: [How to embed fonts in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html)

Once you have that, then the second step is to simply generate the HTML page text dynamically (with the font code in it and your NFO) and then stick that into the WebBrowser control.