# How can i use the nice ttf fonts in my website?

Tags: xhtml

everyone knows that we are restricted to use the windows native fonts like arial, verdana etc.. in websites.

but i want to use nice fonts which are available in TTF format.

i know it can be done by a php code to make the text as a picture, but that's bad , i want it to be selectionable..

example: http://typekit.com/libraries/full

you can select those cute fonts, means they are REAL.

typekit is a paid service, i'm looking for similar way, or a free service.

Thanks

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-encode the TTF font into the EOT font format if you want to use a custom font in IE. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_OpenType

Other browsers may support TTF directly.