# How to embed a font in website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to embed my custom font in my website, got a link folder from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator this site after uploading a font on this site, it gives me this CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'VoltaEFTU-Regular';
    src: url('voltaeftu-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'),
    url('voltaeftu-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('voltaeftu-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('voltaeftu-regular-webfont.svg#webfonttKmU3jX8') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

But it's not working on my machines. How can I embed a font in my website?

Thanks 
Mayur Mate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed fonts in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html)

Comment: The keywords are in the title of your question. Just type them in some search box like: google, stackoverflow, no matter, you will find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were doing it, I would take a look at how the [Google Font API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/) works…

Comment: Thnaks Evry one i use a js to convert this font.
by using following website.......

http://typeface.neocracy.org/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

`@font-face` code looks correct, but if you want use this font example in `<p>` you must use `font-family: 'VoltaEFTU-Regular';` in this element. Look into generated *demo.html* file.