# Embed a font in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to embed a font in the html / javascript code? (everything in 1 html file)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html

Comment: i want everything in the same file

Comment: Is there a particular reason it has to be in one file?  This sounds quite artificial, and I wouldn't be surprised if there's some way of using e.g. sIFR that fits in with your situation.  If you post the *full* constraints people will be able to give you fuller answers.

Comment: I suggest you base64 the font file and embed it as a Data URI.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Cufón](http://github.com/sorccu/cufon) may be your best bet. Its [font converter](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) turns OTF, TTF, PFB, and PostScript fonts into JavaScript. You can also limit the converted fonts to certain glyph subsets to reduce file size. Read more here:

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about

Usually you'd want to include the resultant JavaScript files externally (to aid cacheing and ease development and maintenance), but for your purposes, you can just include it all within `<script>` elements in the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a font file as css code by converting it to base64 and embedding it as a Data URI.

I'll break down the steps below:

1. Convert font to dataURI (https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file)

[image]

2. Embed it in CSS via @font-face.

```html
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Merriweather';
    src: url('data:@file/x-font-ttf;base64,AAEAAAARAQAABAAQR0RFRo9QjtMAAANAAAAB9Ed...')
         format('ttf');
    font-weight: 400;
}
</style>
```

You're all set!