# How to show a particular font on client's computer

Tags: fonts

I have a website which needs a certain font to display its content properly. Now I want to install it in client's computer if it is not available there.

What is the way to do this? Is there any way to make the font available in client's computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS embedded fonts:

http://randsco.com/index.php/2009/07/04/p680
http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol3/css_no15.htm

Related:
[How to embed fonts in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html)

Comment: That answer requires a note about browser support. I believe recent browsers support it reasonably well, but older browsers just don't, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a license to distribute the font, you can embed it in the web page using font-face, and link to the .ttf (or whatever) file for download. If you don't have a license to distribute it, you can still embed it on the web page (using - in roughly ascending order of 'goodness' - an image, sifr, cufon, or font-face) but you won't be able to distribute it for download.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, why not just include the font in the webpage? http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/presto-2-2-and-opera-10-a-first-look/#webfonts

Answer (score 1):

Until 2 years ago this was almost impossible. Now, all the major browser support the css `@font-face` property. Here is a good tutorial on `@font-face`: http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/

(be careful: use only fonts with an open license or that you have the right to use on web pages)