# Embedding fonts in IE

Tags: fonts, embed, font-face

I have a site that uses custom fonts.
I've got the font form the designer in oft format.
I've used a converter to convert them to eot format.

and added the following code to the css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AdumaFOTRegular';
    src: url('fonts/AdumaFOT-Regular.eot');
    src: local('AdumaFOTRegular'), local('AdumaFOTRegular'), url('fonts/AdumaFOT-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

This works great in FF and chrom but doesn't work in IE.
The sample site is here: http://test.hannitcohen.co.il/eshkol/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed fonts in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html)

Comment: See the 2nd answer for a complete rundown on how to make things work in all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some converters don't make a usable .eot converted font. When it comes to converting fonts into a .eot, I've had success with this site: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi