# Custom font via CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I am learning php, html and css now and I'm trying to use a custom font on my site. I found the `@font-face` property that allows to make that, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
css:

```
@font-face {font-family: LazurskiCTT;src:url(../sources/fonts/ie/LazurskiCTT Regular.eot);}
/*IE*/ 
@font-face {font-family:LazurskiCTT;src:url(../sources/fonts/LazurskiCTT Regular.Ttf);}
/*Other browsers*/
#myFonts{font-family:LazurskiCTT;}
```

html:

```
<p id="myFonts">Lazurski</p>
```

Maybe it's because I use it on my local machine? I run it in FireFox.

Comment: If you are declaring it exactly like that, I believe that the second rule will win (even if the browser doesn't understand the font file type). See [this blog post](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) on `@font-face`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest (and best) way to get it to work is to use fontsquirrel's generator:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your font path are correct try this. Quote's... some say it not necessary, but i find it to work best. In some cases my CSS breaks without the quotes (Especially when white space is involved in path).

Note: Use this site to convert your ttf to eot for it to work on IE (Place both .ttf & .eot in same directory). http://ttf2eot.sebastiankippe.com/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "LazurskiCTT"; 
    src:url("../sources/fonts/ie/LazurskiCTT Regular.eot"); /*IE*/
    src:url("../sources/fonts/LazurskiCTT Regular.Ttf") format("truetype"); /*Non-IE*/

}
```

This works for my site. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a slash `/` after `..`, that may already be it.

Note that most Linux-based systems are case sensitive - the `.Ttf` may not work if it's not written *exactly* that way.

For a detailed walk-through how to set up custom fonts across browsers, also see this question: [Error while using the custom fonts in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770039/error-while-using-the-custom-fonts-in-css)

Comment: @Kevin the answer consisted of the "you are missing a slash" bit only initially - it grew afterwards, unexpectedly :)

Comment: What wiki?? I have a construction but can't run it.

Comment: thanx, the font extention is *.Ttf.

Answer (score 2):

It should work on your local machine. Try the following.

Make sure that the path to your font is correct.

```
@font-face {
font-family: CustomFont;
src: url('CustomFont.otf');
}
p {font-family:CustomFont, Helvetica, Arial}
```

---

```
<p>Text here</p>
```

Comment: Thanx, I try try, but no result. Font squirrel is a good thing, maybe it will useful.