# How to display Burmese characters on website and record them in MySQL if the user doesn't have the font?

Tags: html, mysql, unicode, fonts

I need to develop a website for a client in Myanmar. The website will obviously be in the Burmese language and they want it to be readable by people who do not have Burmese fonts on their machine.

I know wikipedia managed to [do it here](http://my.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3a%E1%80%97%E1%80%9F%E1%80%AD%E1%80%AF%E1%80%85%E1%80%AC%E1%80%99%E1%80%BB%E1%80%80%E1%80%BA%E1%80%94%E1%80%BE%E1%80%AC#Enabling_the_web_fonts_extension_here) but I still haven't found how.

Will I have to write the Burmese characters using their HTML unicode codepoints? I have already found a library that manages to display Burmese characters if I provide the Unicode codepoint so I guess this is an option.

The other problem is that they want to insert Burmese text in a MySQL database. How am I going to store it? Using which encoding in MySQL? And then how to display it on machines that do not have Burmese fonts installed?

I hope I am clear and not too confusing.

Comment: I think if you add UTF-8 encoding in your meta tag and also in your db you're good to go. I did this for persian fonts and it worked

Comment: Your meta tag can be like this <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: thanks! I assume the persian font was not installed on your machine? Did you also use @font-face for font replacement?

Comment: Well on that time there wasn't still css3, so no. But I think it will work, maybe not in older browsers...

Answer (score 4):

The Wikimedia page mentioned in the question use the free [Tharlon font](http://code.google.com/p/tharlon-font/) as a downloadable font (via `@font-face'). It is a Unicode-encoded font, so you can enter the real Burmese characters in UTF-8 encoding. Depending on your authoring tools, you might need some extra utility in order to type characters, like Windows Character Map or my [Full Unicode Input](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8) utility (select block Myanmar).

Answer (score 2):

Embedding custom fonts can be done, follow the below link

[Custom font via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985097/custom-font-via-css)

Storing Burmese, you can use nvarchar or ntext or similar data types in your SQL to store

It will be stored as is and will be rendered as is.

Comment: thanks. But how to enter text into my html file? Can I type it directly using a burmese keyboard, and the @font-face will display it correctly in the browser if the user does not have burmese font installed?

Comment: Html has to be set as UTF-8, and with burmese font installed on your machine you should be able to type in burmese, however if you want the font to be displayed properly you need the above link to download the font runtime.