# how to target an element using '@font-face' tag

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a logo using a custom font... and want to embed it in my CSS

For example: my div element is id:"logo"

Would I just use this?

```
#logo {
    font-family: myNewFont;
    src: url('ufonts.com_gotham-medium.woff');
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom font via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985097/custom-font-via-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myNewFont;
    src: url('ufonts.com_gotham-medium.woff');
}    
#logo {
    font-family: myNewFont;
}
```