# CSS - font style: Italic - Slant to left

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML and I made it italic using CSS.

Is it possible to reverse the slant position of the text from right to left?

**HTML**

```
<p class="italic">hello world</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Look at this answer, maybe it help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11976302/8283938

Answer (score 7):

hmmm, as I correct understand, just try this:

```
.italic {
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translate(0px, 0px) skew(30deg, 0deg);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, it work https://jsfiddle.net/mzo2wuoo/

Comment: Cool, you're welcome :)

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting scale, rotate and translate to zero?

Comment: Ohh, just for a demo purposes, would be enough that one:
.italic {
    transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
}

Comment: Note: `<span>` elements will need `display:inline-block` (or similar) otherwise the transform will not be not applied.