# how to know format of fonts

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am going to use @font-face. So I copied **corbel** font to my directory and there it shows 4 fonts `CORBEL_0.TTF , CORBELB_0.TTF , CORBELI_0.TTF , CORBELZ_0.TTF` and next I copied **Kozuka Gothic Pro** font to my directory and there it shows 6 fonts `KozGoPro-Bold.otf , KozGoPro-ExtraLight.otf , KozGoPro-Heavy.otf , KozGoPro-Light.otf , KozGoPro-Medium.otf , KozGoPro-Regular.otf`

How to write src using @font-face rule?
As in example url("../../css/fonts/League_Gothic.eot") format('eot'); the format eot , is it the extension of font? Anyone give me the idea for full syntax within @font-face.

Comment: Please consult the CSS reference of your choice first.

Comment: I need two font-family and I would like to use it in font-face.

Comment: Sure, as written, consult a CSS reference. This is very basic material and you haven't even outlined what you did research so far for your wantings. I wonder you even think you're the first one who wants to know this.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [How to embed fonts in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/220236/367456)

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face
{
font-family: corbel;
src: url('/fonts/corbel.ttf'),
 url('/fonts/corbel.eot'); 
} 

@font-face
{
font-family: Kozuka;
src: url('/fonts/Kozuka.ttf'),
 url('/fonts/Kozuka.eot'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Kozuka Gothic Pro';
    src: url("../../css/fonts/Kozuka Gothic Pro.otf") format('truetype');
    src: local("☺"),
    url("../../css/fonts/KozGoPro-Bold.otf"),
    url("../../css/fonts/KozGoPro-ExtraLight.otf") format('truetype'), 
    url("../../css/fonts/KozGoPro-Heavy.otf") format('truetype'), 
    url("../../css/fonts/KozGoPro-Light.otf") format('truetype');
    url("../../css/fonts/KozGoPro-Medium.otf") format('truetype')
    url("../../css/fonts/KozGoPro-Regular.otf") format('truetype');
}
```