# How to implement tamil font for my website?

Tags: php, codeigniter, fonts, tamil

I have developed the website in codeigniter, now i want to add tamil fonts in my website . 
Type the description in tamil, and add the description value into the description table desc colum and retrieve the desc values and display that tamil content to my website..

Answer (score 5):

## You can do it with CSS3!

Before the functionality didn't actually exist beyond having the font pre-installed.  Tamil fonts are unicode and often are ttf files.  So make sure you have the ttf file on your web-server in order to have it available for use.

```
<style> 
@font-face
{
    font-family: myTamilFont;
    src: url(tamil_font.ttf);
}

div
{
    font-family: myTamilFont;
}
</style>
```

*This will not work IE8 and below*

---

For more information: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_fonts.asp

Similar question asked on StackOverflow: [How to embed fonts in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

Use meta tag char set utf8 for using tamil font...
for insert database you should use ..
**mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");**

Hope this will help you