# Custom fonts are being loaded into the webpage

Tags: php, css

Can somebody assist me? I'm utilizing specified fonts in my internet project. Anonymous users could not understand how to download, install, and use these fonts. If the fonts are not installed, the website seems to be functional. Is there any means, or any central portal for fonts, where individual fonts may be uploaded and shared for use? Jquery, like bootstrap, provides libraries for usage.

Comment: create webfonts and keep the files in your server.

Comment: can u go for google fonts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Web Fonts. Using CSS like this, you can tell the browser to download fonts from a URL and use them on the page:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('Graublau Web Regular'), local('Graublau Web'),
    url("GraublauWeb.woff") format("woff"),
    url("GraublauWeb.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("GraublauWeb.svg#grablau") format("svg");
}
```

<sup>Source: [@fencepost's answer to How to embed fonts in HTML? on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967226/1414639)</sup>

[Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) is an example of a service that hosts font files. Typekit is another.

You can roll your own, but you will need to convert the file to all the necessary formats to ensure compatibility. IANAL, but you may wish to to check the legality of hosting your own fonts before you do so.

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS3 feature you can use custom fonts. you just need to upload the fonts on the server and define the path in css code.

Few fonts required different format types to work on different OS.  so you can use [online font converter](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create all font type format .

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: it this solution work for you, you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## **Use Google Fonts**

Here is the [link](https://www.google.com/fonts).

How to use it? Look for `quick use` button.

**1. Choose a Font to use and select its style**

here, I'll be using `Open Sans`.

**2. Create CSS Link to page**

then, google will generate its link for use. Example:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>'
```

use that in your page.

**3. Add rule to CSS script**

on your css script, add:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Actually, Google Font is pretty straight forward. Make sure to use `quick use` button to see what I mean.

[image: Quick-use button]