# Visual C# (2015) web browser not displaying some fonts

Tags: c#, fonts, webbrowser-control

Our marketing department has created web pages that use specific fonts for special purposes.  These fonts get installed onto the local system when our users install our software.  If I view one of these pages in Google Chrome, I can see the icon from a special font just fine (the circled item in the "Download quick start guide" image below):

[image: Content as seen in Chrome]

However, I cannot see the icon from the font in a browser that I implemented using the "WebBrowser" component that is in Visual C# (2015).  I should also point out that I cannot see the font if I view the page with the Edge browser.

My question: **Is there a property that I can change (or something else I can do) within the WebBrowser component that will allow the font to display?**

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html

Comment: So, if I'm reading the suggestions above right, basically the solution is in how the page is written and not necessarily how I have the browser coded, correct?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as "That solved my problem" but it doesn't appear to in this case.  The web page author provided me with a CSS that had similar code to what you referenced and it didn't work.  He's just going to resort to using an image for now.