# How to use google fonts in VS code

Tags: html, css

I am making a resume and I was wondering how to use google fonts in vs code. I downloaded the font but can't figure out how to link it.

Comment: Are you talking about changing the font in Visual Studio Code itself or on your website?

Comment: changing on my website

Comment: @Sergius answer will work. But in most cases, I think you'd be better off just embedding your font. First off, it's much easier and extremely fast, but there's a lot of other useful cases for embedding it. 
Read Google Fonts docs on how to embed Google Fonts:
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2

Let me know if you need further help

Comment: The question is not about what you ask in the description. You might have asked for 'How to use google fonts in my website' or something like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to embed fonts in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to download the font at all. All you need to do is:

1. go to https://fonts.google.com
2. select all the fonts you want to use by clicking on the plus button with "select this style".
3. then, at the right side of the screen you can "use on web" click on import
4. copy the @import line and paste it into your css
5. to use the font, go to right again and down to the bottom, copy the font name.
6. paste that in your code where you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. search fonts on google fonts.
2. Install fonts.
3. Open Setting in Vs code editor.
4. Go to .json file and Enter the installed fonts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtRPZ.png)