# how to use a specific font folder in my web site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fonts on the Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233/fonts-on-the-web)

I have font folder of volta regular with license but i dont know how to use it in web site. Coz i dont want to replace it while user's machine don't have that font please tell me any solution to sort out this problem, Did have to upload it on server ?

Thanks 
Mayur

Comment: Dupe: How to embed fonts in HTML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220236/how-to-embed-fonts-in-html also be careful, the fact that you have "a license" does not necessarily mean you are allowed to use the font on a web site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805324/how-to-use-web-fonts-legally

Comment: which language you are user like java, .net, rails etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these:

- [Google Webfonts](http://code.google.com/webfonts)
- [@font-face](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten)
- [typeface](http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html)