# Licensing Issues with embeding fonts using CSS3

Tags: css, fonts, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use web-fonts legally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805324/how-to-use-web-fonts-legally)

I'm making a website and want to embed some nice fonts in my css file using `@font-face`.

With regard to copyright issues: what are the guidelines for what fonts I may embed. For example if a font costs money, but I have paid for it in a personal capacity, may I use it on my personal web site?

Additionally, how can I find out the licensing of fonts that I want to use?

Comment: Perhaps somebody knows what the `Font Embedability` means in `Fonts->Right Click on Font->Properties->Details`. If it says "editable" can I embed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally a font you've purchased for personal use is not licensed for distribution, which you are essentially doing with @font-face - hence the popularity of tools like sIFR.

I often create image files for largely this reason -- while I know it is not popular, and there are some great new options, it is simply the most compatible and keeps me sane.

Answer (score 3):

It depends of each font of course. look for a readme file or the page when you download the font.

If you need free fonts check out [google webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

Comment: Google Web Fonts is a great resource for finding high quality fonts, embeddable to your website for free. I've checked it out once before but the choice of fonts was very limited. It seems like they got a whole lot more since then.

Answer (score 2):

This site is a nice little guide into font faces and gives a couple of sites that offer free font faces. http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/

Answer (score 0):

If you paid for the font it doesn't mean your licence allows embeding, chances are it doesn't. There are numerous free fonts you can embed or you can use paid services like [typekit](http://typekit.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Another great paid service is [Fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/). Unlike Typekit it's a one-time fee per font and you handle the hosting etc yourself.