# Does one need to have a license for fonts if we are using ttf files in itext?

Tags: fonts, licensing, itext, font-embedding

I understand that itext does not come with any of the font libraries and you need to provide the font library . 
The pdf once generated, will be viewed by Acrobat and assuming , it is the standard fonts, adobe would have support for it.
My questions is about licensing of the fonts.

a) Do I need to have a license of the fonts which I am using in iText ? For eg if I am using Arial, one of the most commonly used font and which is not free, do I need to purchase the font ?

b) If I using any specific font for eg STSONG.ttf , for Chinese characters, do I need to have a license for this ?

Comment: Usually there is license information shipped with the font. You have to check that license information.

Comment: Good to have comment coming from the creator of iText. I What I have read from licensing docs, if on ships the font, packaged in application, then you should have license. If I create a pdf in windows, I need not worry about the license as windows comes packaged with the font files. For itext, this must be a common issue faced by all developers. Do we need to have a license for something as common as Arial.ttf ?

Comment: I'll elaborate in an answer. Please give me a moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a general question [How to use web-fonts legally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805324/how-to-use-web-fonts-legally) on StackOverflow that was closed as off-topic, yet some answers are interesting.

Just like all software (including iText), fonts are licensed, but there are different types of licenses.

- You have fonts that have an open font license like [SIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIL_Open_Font_License) which is the first that comes to mind, but there are many other licenses that allow you to use a font completely for free. **Caveat:** be careful with "free" fonts on the web. Many are just copies of protected fonts with their copyright notices removed.
- You have fonts that are proprietary in the sense that you can not redistribute them, but they allow you to embed the font in documents. For instance: the fonts that ship with MS Windows are proprietary. You are not allowed to copy them and ship them for free, however some fonts may be embedded within document files. Embedding allows fonts to travel with documents. Embedded fonts can only be used to print, preview and in some cases edit the document in which they are embedded. (See [Font redistribution and license issues](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/faq/faq11.htm) in Microsoft's FAQ)
- Some fonts require a full (paid) license even if you want to embed them. If I remember correctly, the fonts you can download as a font pack for Adobe Acrobat/Reader can only be used in the context of Acrobat. You are not allowed to embed them in a document using software that is not sold by Adobe.

I have different font examples in the [sandbox](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox) and for every font I use, I look at the [corresponding license](https://github.com/itext/sandbox/tree/master/resources/fonts/licenses). If you check the [overview](https://github.com/itext/sandbox/blob/master/resources/fonts/licenses/overview.txt), you'll see that I have fonts with a SIL license, an Apache license, and so on... I don't know about STSONG.ttf, so you'll have to check which license applies.

You were also asking explicitly about Arial. [Arial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial) was created for the [Monotype Imaging Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotype_Imaging). The [Monotype Imaging EULA](http://www.fonts.com/info/legal/eula/monotype-imaging) states:

> You may embed the Font Software only into an electronic document that
>   (i) is not a Commercial Product, (ii) is distributed in a secure
>   format that does not permit the extraction of the embedded Font
>   Software, and (iii) in the case where a recipient of an electronic
>   document is able to Use the Font Software for editing, only if the
>   recipient of such document is within your Licensed Unit.

However, you probably didn't obtain the font from Monotype. It was probably shipped with your legal copy of Microsoft Windows, and Monotype may have licensed its fonts to Windows under a license that is less strict.

Let's check which license applies by right clicking a font file such as arial.ttf in C:\windows\fonts and let's inspect the Properties:

[image]

I am in luck: in my case, the Font embeddability says "Editable". This means that I can embed the font in a document not only to print and (pre)view the document, but also to edit the document (e.g. edit form fields) as long as I use arial.ttf in the context of the Windows license that I bought. I can not copy arial.ttf to another computer.

Note that you shouldn't assume that was always the case. For instance if we look at [Arial Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS), we see that older versions only allowed print and preview embedding, whereas editable embedding was allowed only for version 1.00 and higher. You should really check the properties of each font you are planning to use.

If you need a font that can be distributed, you should look for an alternative font that has an open font license. I use FreeSans in the sandbox examples, but there are other [free alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial#Free_alternatives).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Makes things much clear. And from what I see, if I am generating the pdf on linux box, I need to install arial.ttf on linux. Windows comes with arial.ttf and since I purchased windows, from the licensing standpoint, I am fine.  But not for linux

Comment: If you want to avoid the licensing nightmare and use NOTO fonts release by google and supported by adobe. Here is how to use with iText http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237980/itext-pdf-not-displaying-chinese-characters-when-using-noto-fonts-or-source-hans

Comment: Yes @vsingh I didn't know about the NOTO fonts, but I've downloaded them all and I intend to use/promote them in my examples. Great resource!