# How to display chinese characters in pdf using itextg 5.5.9 in android

Tags: java, android, fonts, itext, chinese-locale

I am using itextg 5.5.9 for generating a pdf. All the english characters are displayed correctly but the chinese characters are not displayed. Is there any way to display chinese characters on pdf.

Here is the code.

```
Font fontbold = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman", 11, Font.BOLD);
Font fontTimes = FontFactory.getFont("Times-Roman", 11);
    protected void generatePDF(String txn_id) {

    remark=et_customer_remark.getText().toString().trim();
    getEmployeeBranchAddress();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yy"); // Just the year, with 2 digits
    String year = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
    int nextYear=1+Integer.parseInt(year);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Filename=txn_id.replaceAll("/", "-");
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String yy = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String mm = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String dd = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    Bitmap signatureBitmap = mSignaturePadEngineer.getSignatureBitmap();
    Bitmap signatureBitmapCust = mSignaturePadCustomer.getSignatureBitmap();
    if (addSignatureToGallery(signatureBitmap, signatureBitmapCust)) {
        /*
         * Toast.makeText(ServiceReportActivity.this,
         * "Signature saved into the Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
         */
        try {
            Document document = new Document();
            document.open();

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "CRM_PDF/PDFReports/");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs(); // create root directory in sdcard
            }

            File gpxfile = new File(root, EIIEMPID + "-" + Filename + ".pdf");
            // pdf file
            // in that
            attachmentPath = gpxfile.getParent();
            Log.e("Attachment_path 2211", attachmentPath+EIIEMPID + "-" + Filename + ".pdf");
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(gpxfile));

            File file = new File(
                    getAlbumStorageDir("SignaturePadEnginner"),
                    "SignatureEnginner.jpg");
            InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
            int height = bmp.getHeight();
            int width = bmp.getWidth();
            height = height / 4;
            bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            File filecustomer = new File(
                    getAlbumStorageDir("SignaturePadCustomer"),
                    "SignatureCustomer.jpg");
            InputStream fileInputStreamCustomer = new FileInputStream(
                    filecustomer);
            Bitmap bmpCustomer = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(fileInputStreamCustomer);
            int heightCustomer = bmpCustomer.getHeight();
            int widthCustomer = bmpCustomer.getWidth();
            heightCustomer = heightCustomer / 4;
            bmpCustomer = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpCustomer,
                    widthCustomer, heightCustomer, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream streamCutomer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmpCustomer.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
                    streamCutomer);

            try {
                imgSignEngineer = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                imgSignCustomer = Image
                        .getInstance(streamCutomer.toByteArray());// imagesign
                // ofcustomer
            } catch (BadElementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            InputStream inputStream = ServiceReportActivity.this
                    .getAssets().open("logo.jpeg");
            Bitmap bmpLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream streamLogo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmpLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, streamLogo);
            Image imgLogo;
            imgLogo = Image.getInstance(streamLogo.toByteArray());
            imgLogo.scalePercent(35);

            document.open();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
            table.setWidthPercentage(100);
            // document.add(imgSign);

            Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();

            //Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/Verdana.ttf");

            Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN);
            font.setSize(20);

            p3.setFont(font);
            p3.add("Service Report Cum Proforma Invoice:" + txn_id);
            p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            Paragraph paraDate = new Paragraph();
            Font fontDate = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN);
            fontDate.setSize(10);
            paraDate.setFont(fontDate);
            StringBuilder strBuildDateCurrent = new StringBuilder("Date : "
                    + strEndDateNTime);
            String strDate = strBuildDateCurrent.toString();
            paraDate.add(strDate);
            paraDate.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);

            document.add(p3);
            document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            PdfPCell cell;
            Paragraph parahHeadInfo = new Paragraph(
                    "No.20,Jingke Rd.,Nantun District,Taichung City 408,Taiwan", fontbold);
            Paragraph parahHeadInfo2 = new Paragraph(
                    strBranchAddress+"\nPh. No : "+ "N/A"+"\nCUSTOMER CARE HELPLINE : N/A \nEmail : info@accutex.com.tw\nWeb site : https://www.accutex.com.tw",
                    fontTimes);
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.addElement(imgLogo);
            cell.addElement(parahHeadInfo);
            cell.addElement(parahHeadInfo2);
            cell.setColspan(5);
            cell.setRowspan(11);
            table.addCell(cell);

            Paragraph parahHeadInfo3 = new Paragraph(
                    "Case No : "
                            + CaseID
                            +"\nPriority : "
                            + casePriority
                            + "\nService Report Cum Proforma Invoice No : "
                            + txn_id
                            + "\nDate : "
                            + strStartDateNTime
                            /*+ "\nGST No : "+ "N/A"*/+"\nSERVICE ACCOUNTING CODE (SAC) : N/A / N/A",fontbold);
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.addElement(parahHeadInfo3);
            cell.setColspan(5);
            cell.setRowspan(11);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Name: "
                    + strCustomerName, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(6);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ph. No: " + phn_no, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(4);
            table.addCell(cell);

            // table.addCell("Customer Name: " + strCustomerName);
            // table.addCell("Ph. No: " + strCustomerPhoneNo);
            // table.addCell("Customer Name: " + strCustomerName);

            String strTempAddress = custaddress;
            strTempAddress = strCustomerAddress.replace("\n", " ");
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Address: "
                    + strTempAddress, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            /*cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer GST No : "
                    + strGSTNo, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);*/


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Contact Person & M.No.: "
                    + strContactPersonName + " " + strContactPersonMobNo,
                    fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(6);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(
                    "Designation: " + strDesignation, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(4);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Machine", fontbold));
            cell.setColspan(1);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Principal: " + strMachineMake,
                    fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Model: " + strModel, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sr. No: " + strSrNo, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Details", fontbold));
            cell.setColspan(1);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Controller Make: "
                    + strControlMake, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("System No: " + strSystemNo,
                    fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);

            /*cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Hour Count : " + strHourCount, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);*/

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Type of Visit ", fontbold));
            cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            cell.setColspan(1);

            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Installation:" + strInstalation
                    + "\nAMC:" + strAmc, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Chargeable:" + strChargable
                    + "\nNon Chargeable:" + strNonchargbl, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Warranty service:" + strWarrnty
                    + "\nOther:" + strOther, fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(3);
            table.addCell(cell);
            /*
             * cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MSR_CauseNRemedy)));
             * params.put("MSR_Remark",
             * cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MSR_Remark)));
             */
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Complaint: "
                    + customer_complain + "\n\n", fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Causes & Remedy: "
                    + causes_remedy + "\n\n\n", fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            Paragraph parahWorkStartDateTime = new Paragraph(
                    "Work Started date/time : " + strStartDateNTime,
                    fontTimes);
            Paragraph parahWorkEndDateTime = new Paragraph(
                    "Work ends date/time     : " + strEndDateNTime,
                    fontTimes);
            Paragraph parahWorkTotalDays = new Paragraph(
                    "Total days                     : " + strTotalDays,
                    fontTimes);

            Paragraph parahChargePerDay = new Paragraph(
                    "Charges per day*billable days : " + strChargedPerDay
                            + " * " + strBilableDays, fontTimes);

            Paragraph parahCheckNo_Date = new Paragraph(
                    "Cheque No. & Date      : " + strchqno + " " + strDate,
                    fontTimes);

            Paragraph parahDrawnOn = new Paragraph(
                    "Drawn on               : " + strDrawnOn, fontTimes);

            Paragraph parahBankName_Branch = new Paragraph(
                    "Bank name & branch  : " + strbankName, fontTimes);

            /*
             * Paragraph parahAmount = new Paragraph(
             * "Amount                  ________________________",
             * fontTimes);
             */

            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.addElement(parahWorkStartDateTime);
            cell.addElement(parahWorkEndDateTime);
            cell.addElement(parahWorkTotalDays);
            cell.addElement(parahCheckNo_Date);
            cell.addElement(parahDrawnOn);
            cell.addElement(parahBankName_Branch);
            // cell.addElement(parahAmount);
            cell.setColspan(5);
            table.addCell(cell);

            Paragraph parahTotalCharge = new Paragraph("Amount  : "
                    + strAmount, fontTimes);
            /*
             * Paragraph parahFareCharges = new Paragraph(
             * "Fare Charges   ________________________", fontTimes);
             */
            Paragraph parahLocalConveyance = new Paragraph(
                    "Local Conveyance  : " + strlocalConvenc, fontTimes);
            Paragraph parahOtherCharges = null;
            /*if(FlagChargable==1){
                parahOtherCharges = new Paragraph(
                        "GST Type : "+ strServiceTypeTax, fontTimes);
            }else{
                // Paragraph parahOtherCharges = new Paragraph("Service Tax Type :"+ strServiceTypeTax, fontTimes);
            }*/

            Paragraph parahSeviceTax = new Paragraph(
                    "Service Tax Amount : "+ strGSTServiceTax, fontTimes);
            Paragraph parahTotalCharges = new Paragraph(
                    "Total Charges  : " + strTotalCharges, fontTimes);
            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.addElement(parahChargePerDay);
            cell.addElement(parahTotalCharge);
            // cell.addElement(parahFareCharges);
            cell.addElement(parahLocalConveyance);
            cell.addElement(parahOtherCharges);
            cell.addElement(parahSeviceTax);
            cell.addElement(parahTotalCharges);
            cell.setColspan(5);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell();
            Paragraph parahJobIs = new Paragraph("Job is: " + "Completed :"
                    + strcompleted + "     Awaiting for parts :"
                    + strawaitingparts + "     Pending :" + strPending
                    + "     On Contract :" + strOncontract, fontTimes);
            cell.setColspan(10);
            cell.addElement(parahJobIs);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Accepted By Customer: "
                    + acceptedByCustomer + "\n\n", fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Remarks: " + remark + "\n\n",
                    fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Feedback:\n\n",
                    fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Other Engineers : "+multipleEnggName+"\n\n",
                    fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            //By Kiran 31/5/2017
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Contact Name : "+strCustName+"\n\n",fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(10);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Contact Email Id: "+ strCustEmailid+"\n\n", fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(5);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Contact Mobile Number: " + strCustMobile+"\n", fontTimes));
            cell.setColspan(5);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell();
            Paragraph parahSign1 = new Paragraph(
                    "Name & Sign. of Engineer", fontTimes);
            cell.addElement(parahSign1);
            cell.addElement(imgSignEngineer);

            Paragraph paraNAME1 = new Paragraph(service_eng_name, fontTimes);

            cell.addElement(paraNAME1);
            cell.setColspan(5);
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell();
            Paragraph parahSign2 = new Paragraph(
                    "Name & Sign. of Customer", fontTimes);
            cell.addElement(parahSign2);
            cell.addElement(imgSignCustomer);
            Paragraph paraNAME2 = new Paragraph(cust_name, fontTimes);// addd
            // signh
            // to
            // pdf
            cell.addElement(paraNAME2);// addd signh to pdf
            cell.setColspan(5);
            table.addCell(cell);

            document.add(table);
            document.add(paraDate);

            document.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PDF Generated",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(gpxfile), "application/pdf");
            target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here,
                // or
                // something
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Pdf exception", e1.getMessage());
        } catch (BadElementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Pdf exception", e.getMessage());
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("Pdf exception", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(ServiceReportActivity.this,
                "Unable to store the signature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I also tried using `ttf` files but no results. Is there any font like `Times-New Roman` that I should use so that I can generate chinese characters

Comment: Did you search the official web site? See https://itextpdf.com/search?search_api_views_fulltext=Chinese and you'll find plenty of examples that will allow you to answer the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237980/itext-pdf-not-displaying-chinese-characters-when-using-noto-fonts-or-source-hans?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Here is the solution which worked for me

Comment: Indeed, that's one of my answers. I'll close your question as a duplicate so that people with the same question find the solution more quickly.