# Acrobat reader cannot extract the embedded font 'PWLEAX+NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular-Identity-H'

Tags: jasper-reports, acrobat, export-to-pdf

I am using Jasper Report 6.9.0 version with Java 1.8.0_201 and Arial Unicode MS and NotoSerifCJKsc(especially for the traditional Chinese) fonts for the Jasper Report to display the Chinese Characters.

Pdf generated properly and I am able to see the complete content when I open it on the chrome, but if I try to open it with Acrobat reader then I am getting the error

> "Cannot extract the embedded font 'PWLEAX+NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular-Identity-H'.
>
> Some characters may not display or print correctly."

[image]
Is there something that needs to be updated?

Answer (score 2):

This is a most probably a problem of the old itext library that jasper reports are forced to use due to license issues.

If you check dependencies of [Jasper Report 6.9.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.9.0) in fact you will find `com.lowagie » itext  2.1.7.js6`

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29238674/5292302) the developer [Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie) states:

> [*] Update: this problem can be reproduced if you use iText 4.2.x, a version that was released by somebody unknown to iText Group NV. Please use iText versions higher than 5 only.

And you can also read more about a similar problem [here](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-cjk/issues/38), basically the pdf's font-extensions seem to be not generated correctly by this old version of itext library.

## Solutions:

1. Change font, try with another font.

or

2. Change to jasper-reports version 6.0 interesting is that this
   version has the
   [dependence](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.0.0)
   to `com.itextpdf » itextpdf 5.5.0` (for this version they somehow had a license to use a new version of itext)

Answer (score 1):

A recent update to Adobe Reader introduced a change that caused Reader to start raising this error on PDF files produced by iText (and maybe other products).

Adobe just announced a new release of Reader that corrects this issue (19.012.20040).

See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2645745