# How to use a specific font in CSS?

Tags: css

I have used the "Crisp" font in Photoshop and now I want to use it in HTML and CSS in macromedia. How to use the font there?

Comment: I assume by "crisp" you mean a specific font style? This is not entirely trivial. What format do you have the font in? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969323/non-standard-fonts-in-web

Comment: Crisp refers to a certain font anti-aliasing mode. This is usually controlled at a Operating System level and is not modifiable through CSS

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to control anti aliasing in webkit browsers like this:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: none;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Is that what you're looking for?