# How do I insert a custom font to text with CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I use custom fonts in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606839/how-would-i-use-custom-fonts-in-css)

How can i use CSS to set a custom font type in, lets say, a `<div>` ?

I've seen something mentioned about `@font-face` ... but that doesn't seem to work in IE or Chrome.

Comment: Also [Non-Standard fonts in web?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2969323)

Comment: [This](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) page works with me in chrome 11, and using the IE9 dev kit it appears to work for all versions of IE (although that may be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@font-face is fully suported in every browser, even in ie.
Notice, that some browsers need fonts to be converted to specific format.
Use [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to do that.

there's a yeasy way to register fonts with [google webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

also you should read [that](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/comparison-of-web-fonts-solutions)

Comment: Are there any limitations to the kinds of font i can use ? I've tried like 3 different custom fonts, and it didn't work

Comment: @Yochai, As i said, different browsers use different formats of fonts. To get your font working in every browser you need to specify every format (.eot for IE) in your @font-face declaration. Fontsquirrel does it for you.

Comment: That didn't work either.... seems like it won't work for hebrew font :(

Comment: Ok answer- fontsquirrel Kit, Expert -> Custom Subsetting... -> choose Language

Comment: Those are optimization options, which cut off potentially unused characters. Glad you did it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [@font-face](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) would be the right way, but isn't fully support (by IE, sure).

You can relly on JavaScript to do it on "all" browsers. I suggest [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/).

Comment: Nope, didn't work.. but Cufon looks nice

Comment: Cufon looks nice, but you can't select text you're rendering with it. :/

Comment: Fail. I couldn't get any of this to work with non-english font (didn't try english font)

Comment: On Cufón web page, remember to explicit specifies chars for special encodings, like **ã** **ü** **ç** etc.

Comment: @seler, it's right. Cufón doesn't allows text selection. Then I aways use it just for titles and places that my texts is "almost" an image but I don't want to crop images to do it.

Comment: What if you want custom font for whole page? http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/comparison-of-web-fonts-solutions

Comment: @seler, nice comparison. But sometimes the *.eot* file size will be very bigger than a Cufón generated *.js*. As I said, I use Cufón for titles and this kind of things. I never needed custom font to all text (Arial is so good). But yes, @font-face is very right to it.