# Google Fonts Open Sans Condensed can't be displayed on some computers

Tags: html, css, fonts

In some computers, in every browser Open Sans Condensed font can't be displayed. Please check JsFiddle example i am using :    http://jsfiddle.net/7hzrcL7c/

I import the code with

```
<style>@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700);</style>
```

In my own computer it shows the font like it supposed to be but in some other computers font seems different. I don't have enough reputation to attach an picture.

Why do some computers can't show the font ? I can access http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700 without any problem from the problematic computers.

Comment: Have you actually set `font-family: 'Open Sans';`?

Comment: yes, check the demo fiddle, it shows fine on my computer.

Comment: Refer to this question and its accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612506/how-can-i-use-helvetica-neue-condensed-bold-in-css