# Sending Font File with a Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, embedded-fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fonts on the Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233/fonts-on-the-web)
>   [Non-Standard fonts in web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969323/non-standard-fonts-in-web)

**Is it possible to send a font with a HTML page like I send external CSS, Javascript files & images?**

I use a unique font & it would be best if I could just send a font file for the browser if it doesn't have that font. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Also [Fonts on the Web](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16233)