# display uninstalled font on a webpage

Tags: unicode, fonts, html, webfonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-Standard fonts in web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969323/non-standard-fonts-in-web)

I have created a Unicode font and I would like to use it on my webpage. I want people to see and read the font. Can they do it without installing the font? Something like run the font from server?

If I remember correctly, I have seen this long time back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may do this using [CSS3's @font-face](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) feature. But you have to provide the necessary font formats.

FontSquirrel's [@font-face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) is a nice web tool that does all the dirty work for you. It is very easy to use and creates all the necessary files, including CSS stylesheets and a HTML example file.

What's really valuable is that it includes all formats and hacks needed to display the font in all major browsers, something which is not so easy to get right.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know i could do that with css : )

Answer (score 2):

You can use  @font-face

In your css you the font would be declared using the @font-face rule.You can specify the font family, specify the links to the fonts in the different formats.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); 
}
```

In your html you then call it using font-family

```
body 
{
   font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) your example helped