# Display fonts that are not installed on the pc

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been looking at services like "Font Deck" and "Typekit" - are there any free alternatives to these?

I want to be able to display fonts that are not installed on the web-users PC (without having to use images)

Can you help me out?

Comment: http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-Standard fonts in web?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969323/non-standard-fonts-in-web)

Comment: There are several existing questions on the same topic, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233/fonts-on-the-web

Answer (score 4):

Google Web Fonts is your best option to provide fonts using CSS to users who don't have the fonts.

Or you can create your own web font using: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

However you must be aware of the licensing issues surrounding the particular font.

Comment: Thnak you! Is using Google SEO friendly?

Comment: @CSS_maniac This has zero to do with SEO in and of itself, save for the inclusion of optimisation/page-load times in the criteria of things affecting SEO. Yes, this can make your pages _much_ slower, which could affect SEO, but would mostly annoy users firstly, use carefully.

Comment: Google Web Fonts tell you how much of an impact the fonts selected will have on the page's loading time, other than that it is SEO neutral.

Answer (score 1):

If licenced properly you can host your own fonts and integrate them into your website using css [@font-face](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface).

Answer (score 0):

Use `@font-face`

Font-face generator: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score -1):

If you have the font installed on your machine and the font is free to use under their licence, you can use **[Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)**. It is a bit oldschool though, but an alternative if you can't use googlefonts for some reason.

It uses javascript to replace the fonts. Works and looks good. Not sure how SEO friendly it is though.

Comment: I do use Typekit, I have a premium account. Would have recommended that if he didn't want a free service (Although they do have a very limited free account). Cufon is a free service, I mention the limitations regarding SEO. Technically it answers his question. And he can use his own judgement on what to use.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted so much, it is an option.