# Getting Mac Fonts to appear in Normal Browsers

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad

I am having trouble getting the font I would like to use, Chalkboard, to work in the Google Chrome browser. I am eventually moving over the HTML and the CSS over to an iPad fo a app, but I would like to at least see it before I move it there.

Is there any browser that actually can detect Chalkboard without going into Quirks Mode? Which one is it?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to use the font? Show some code

Comment: Easy CSS: font-family:"ChalkboardSE";

Comment: But you're not going to use Chrome on the iPad, are you? Is it working in Safari? (And have you considered using the more reliable @font-face method instead that works in *all* modern browsers independent from whether the font is installed or not?)

Comment: Sorry; the link I checked didn't show that font available.

Comment: wait what do you mean @font-face method? explain... I'll have to look about safari,  but I think it is a Mac font loaded only....

Comment: See [Fonts on the Web](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16233) the accepted answer is a bit outdated: The method is now supported by most major browsers, including Chrome. For that to work, however, you need to own an appropriate font license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font Chalkboard is available by default on Macs but not this Chalkboard SE
http://jsfiddle.net/ydRLe/

However, Chalkboard == Chalkboard SE, so just use Chalkboard on your machine to see what it'll look like.

A resource for ya: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: In that case you just need to download the Chalkboard font