# How the browsers display fonts without installing them on my PC

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, fonts

When I tried some of the Asian sites (for example http://www.asahi.com/) it displayed the fonts correctly. I did not install those Asian fonts in my PC. Where the browser is getting the fonts from? Is it always dynamically downloads the font from web server ?

How to implement this support in my web server - Should I generate some java script or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fonts are installed on the browsers.

Though, it is possible to define custom fonts thanks to the [@font-face](http://www.font-face.com/) technology (entirely in CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Search for @font-face, Cufon fonts etc.

Cufon basically is a font-replacement technique that uses javascript and vector graphics to write fonts from a font file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any sign that they specify the font family at all. Certainly the bulk of text is rendered in Times for me, which is the default.

Your default font just includes characters you didn't know it contained.

There are [ways to use custom fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233/fonts-on-the-web) but they aren't using any of them.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the font using css rules, you can add a `src` attribute specifying a url to fetch the font from a remote location.

Try this [link](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) for more info.

Also check out [Google Web Fonts](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/), which can provide you with a selection of fonts relatively easily, by adding an appropriate `link` tag to the header of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC almost certainly *does* include fonts with many Asian characters. When the web page includes characters that are not supported by the default font (such as Times or Verdana) you're using, browsers will automatically find an alternative font and use that instead, so that you still get readable text.

For Firefox, at least, there's a "fontinfo" add-on you can use to determine what font is *actually* being used to display any given piece of text - as it may not be the default font, or the font requested by CSS.

Web sites can use various techniques (including libraries like cufon or typeface.js, though CSS @font-face is usually a better option now that it's widely supported) to provide custom fonts for their pages, but this is not necessary in order for Asian text (for example) to be displayed on a typical PC.